# How to get data from sub url in Python Scrapy

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I am new to scrapy.

I have a table like,

```
<tr>
 <td>name</td> <td>age</td> <td><a href='link to marks'>marks</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>name</td> <td>age</td> <td><a href='link to marks'>marks</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>name</td> <td>age</td> <td><a href='link to marks'>marks</a></td>
</tr>....
```

And the page that has marks has a `<h1 class='marks'>` containing marks.
I am looping tr's and creating an item object,
item['name'] = 'name from td[1]'
item['age'] = 'name from td[2]'
Now, I need to go to the marks link and get the marks and set it to the item, item['marks']

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: You can pass items to responses to new requests using the `meta` attribute of a request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `yield` request with `meta` attribute:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for row in response.xpath('//tr'):
        item = YourItem()
        item["name"] = row.xpath('./td[1]/text()').get()
        item["age"] = row.xpath('./td[2]/text()').get()
        marks_url = row.xpath('./td[3]/a/@href').get()
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url=marks_url,
            meta={"item": item},
            callback=self.parse_marks,
        )

def parse_marks(self, response):
    item = response.meta["item"]
    item["marks] = response.xpath('//your/marks/selector').getall()

    yield item
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was new then. What I was looking for was making an inline_request and getting the marks element. I got it. I haven't thought of this approach, which you have mentioned, it's quite simple. Thank-you